# ¿Diferencia entre anotaciones @Component, @Repository y @Service en Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Las anotaciones anteriores están muy relacionadas, por lo que mis preguntas son las siguientes:

1- ¿Las anotaciones `@Component,` `@Repository` y `@Service` se pueden usar indistintamente en Spring o proporcionan alguna funcionalidad particular además de actuar como una anotación?

En otras palabras, si tengo una clase de servicio y cambio la anotación de `@Service` a `@Component`:

2- ¿seguirá comportándose de la misma manera? o ¿la anotación también influye en el comportamiento y la funcionalidad de la clase?

3-¿Podría por intercambiarlas y por ejemplo utilizar `@Service` cuando conceptualmente debería de tener `@Repository`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`@Repository` y `@Service` son especializaciones de `@Component`, añadiendo un valor semántico que indica la utilidad de la clase anotada (`@Repository` para acceso a BD y `@Service` para la capa de negocio).

Además, las clases marcadas como `@Repository` son elegibles para utilizar un postprocesador `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor`, que traduzca los errores de BD a excepciones de tipo `DataAccessException` (según indica el [javadoc de la clase)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html)

Entiendo que no tendrás problema en cambiar una anotación por otra salvo que uses ese postprocesador.

Comment: Además, según la [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) estas anotaciones podrían conllevar diferencias en el futuro, y se **especifica** que es recomendable utilizar cada anotación para lo que es, por lo que aunque es posible intercambiarlas, no es recomendable.

Answer (score 5):

Como bien dice la [documentación de Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations), **@Component** es el estereotipo principal e indica que una clase con esta anotación es un component o Bean de Spring.

**@Repository**, **@Service** y **@Controller** son especificaciones de la anotación **@Component** para casos concretos, por ejemplo, para la persistencia de datos, servicios o para la capa de presentación respectivamente.

Por lo tanto, puedes anotar tus beans con la anotación **@Component**, pero al  anotarlas con **@Repository**, **@Service** o **@Controller** obtendrás beneficios adicionales ya que algunos de los Spring modules procesan de manera distinta estas anotaciones.

Generalmente puedes utilitzar una en lugar de otra, pero no es recomendado que lo hagas.